# Incremental search/replace in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sublimetext2, incremental-search

So the other day a Sublime lover showed me [how to do incremental search/replace in sublime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXuBgSpLpK4) and asked if I could do that in Visual Studio. After googling I found that Visual Studio does support Incremental Search through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, but there was no obvious way of doing "Replace All". Googling further didn't give any promising results. I did however find that this would require support for multiple carets, which I'm not sure is available or not in VS. Does anyone know how to do that?

*Some possible alternates could be the Rename facility and Find/Replace etc, but none of them is as swift as Incremental Search. I have tried a few add-ins too, but none of them does what the linked video shows.*

Comment: See: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarcoAlamia-CodingLabs.MixEdit and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MultiEditMode

Comment: @jessehouwing: Thanks. MixEdit (your first link) basically does it. The second one proved to be a piece of crap. Unfortunately MixEdit is not free ($10 registration) and currently shows a warning message if u try to install it on VS2017 (works fine though). Anyway it does provide the functionality I was looking for.